# How can I extract the word before and after a specific keyword in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I was wondering what the best way is to get the word before and after a specific keyword from a string?

Example:

```
$e = "Kuru Kavrulmuş soya Fasulye: 100 gram, ortalamadır";
$_GET['word'] = 'soya';
```

I would like to then echo out `Kavrulmuş` and `Fasulye`.

My dynamic snippet is (for getting string)

```
if ( stripos($e, $_GET['word']) !== false) {
    echo '<div class="yellow">'. highlight($e,$_GET['word']) . '</div>';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regex with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match the word before and after your keyword, e.g.

```
$str = "Kuru Kavrulmuş soya Fasulye: 100 gram, ortalamadır"; 
$_GET['word'] = 'soya';

preg_match("/(\w+) " . $_GET['word'] . " (\w+)/mu", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Kavrulmuş soya Fasulye
    [1] => Kavrulmuş
    [2] => Fasulye
)
```

The regex simply explained is to use `\w` for word characters(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) with a quantifier `+` to match 1 or more times. So you can capture the word before and after your keyword.

Comment: There is no benefit to the `m` flag on the pattern (there are no anchors in the pattern).  The user data should probably be `preg_quote()`'d.